# Product rule and integration by parts in Bochner Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(U)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, bochner-spaces

Assume $v(t)\in H_0^1(U)$ for all $0\leq t\leq T$. The weak derivative $v'$ of $v$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\int_0^T \phi'(t)v(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^T\phi(t)v'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\quad\text{for all }\phi\in C_c^\infty([0,T])
\end{equation}
(**Bochner integral**). In **Evans**' proof of the uniqueness of weak solutions of second order hyperbolic pdes one has to calculate
\begin{equation}
I=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_Ua^{ij}\partial_i v\partial_j v+b^i\partial_i v\cdot v\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
The integrand reads pointwise, of course, thinking of $v$ as $[v(t)](x),x\in U,t\in[0,T]$, $\partial_i$ denotes weak derivatives in space; So this is an ordinary Lebesgue integral. We assume $a^{ij}=a^{ij}(x,t),b^i=b^i(x,t)\in C^1(U\times[0,T])$ and $v'(t)\in H_0^1(U)$ for all $t\in[0,T]$. **We can even assume $v\in W^{1,1}(0,T;H_0^1(U))$.**

**I want to prove, that**
\begin{equation}
I=\int_Ua^{ij}\partial_i(v')\partial_j v+b^i\partial_i(v')v\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\int_U\partial_t a^{ij}\partial_i v\partial_j v+\partial_t b^i\partial_i v\cdot v+b^i\partial_i v\cdot v'\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
So usally one would swap integration and derivation in $I$, use product rule and integration by parts. E.g., because of $v(t),v'(t)\in H_0^1(U)$ we got
\begin{equation}
\int_U b^i\partial_i(v')v\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int_U b^i\partial_i v\cdot v'\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
But what is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(a^{ij}\partial_i v\partial_j v+b^i\partial_i v\cdot v\right)
\end{equation}
? **Can we use product rule or integration by parts** in the Bochner Sobolev space?

***Addendum***

I think given that the product rule holds, the problem would reduce to why
\begin{equation}
\partial_i(v')=(\partial_i v)'
\end{equation}
holds, which I should be able to proof using Fubini: We have the formula
\begin{equation}
v(t)=v(0)+\int_0^tv'(s)\,\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}
for all $t\in[0,T]$. Let $\phi\in C_c^\infty(U)$, writing $\partial_i v$ for $t\mapsto \partial_i(v(t))$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int_0^t\int_U(\partial_i v)'\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_U\phi(x)(\partial_i v(t)-\partial_i v(0))\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int_U\partial_i\phi(x)(v(t)-v(0))\,\mathrm{d}x\\=-\int_0^t\int_U\partial_i\phi(x)v'(s)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}s.
\end{equation}
So given sufficient continuity of the integrand we got
\begin{equation}
\int_U(\partial_i v)'\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int_U\partial_i\phi(x)v'(s)\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

Comment: Suggestion: The coefficients $ a^{ij}(x,t) $ and $ b^{ij}(x,t) $ could be found with laplace transforms to allow the use of integration by parts. This way the derivatives, or product rule in the space would be equated to a norm within the space and the integral simplified into linear variables $ x $ and $ t $.